# Websockets stuck in "pending" on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, web-sockets

`ws://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/` seems to cause all of the Stack Oveflow pages to take a while to "load" (by "load" I mean that the browser tab stays for a while like this: [image])

It takes approximately 1.4 minutes for it to fully load:

[image]

Here is my browser information:

```
Google Chrome   28.0.1500.72 (Official Build 211400) m
OS  Windows 
Blink   537.36 (@153022)
JavaScript  V8 3.18.5.9
Flash   11.8.800.97
User Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36
```

---

For all you who *might* say it has to do with my internet speed:

[image]

Comment: What proxy are you behind? This doesn't happen to me (GC/Win7). I do get 502s on a Vodafone network, however

Comment: @JanDvorak I am behind my office's proxy although I have never had this issue before.

Answer (score 39):

I'm 99% sure Web Sockets will always show "pending" in Chrome's web developer tools because the request never actually completes. The `101 Switching Protocol` is what is actually driving the request.

If it's still requesting something, it probably isn't the websocket connection. (it's pending for me, and no loading animation)

Comment: Yes, but then why does the page "load" for about one and a half minutes?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA You aren't using a 1200bd modem, are you? ;)

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA I'm going to guess something else is waiting to do something. Maybe an ajax call that fires at page load? It says pending for me in Chrome 28 and the request has completed.

Comment: @AndrewBarber [Nooo, I do not think so](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jK7qa.png)...

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA Yes... seems to be *slightly* faster than one of those! (and makes our 100Mb fiber here look slow!)

Comment: @AndrewBarber ^_^

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: This is true. I recently faced this issue and doubted on sockets, but on other pages the reloading thing wasn't happening, but no other request as well was showing up. I got really confused and frustated. Then I checked in the code that for image src with incorrect path and onerror trigger for incorrect path was also incorrect, some how, it got stuck in loop and page kept reloading. Mind you, I also stopped my server, but didn't help as well, as soon as I commented img tag, the page loading stopped, and everything worked just fine.

Comment: Or may be you check you src attribute of your image tags, if they are unknown, they should be corrected. This is purely based on observation of what I encountered.

Answer (score 10):

"Pending" is a valid state for WebSockets. You can see the TCP frames being sent and received using the Chrome tools.

[image]

Comment: I see the Data column here, is that the data sent by the server?

Comment: @AftabNaveed Yes.